# Books/papers on model theory in non-monotonic logic

Tags: reference-request, logic, model-theory

I am working on a project whose object language is in non-monotonic logic. Since the project involves reasoning about the models, I am thinking of translating a non-monotonic problem into a first-order logic, use model theory in first-order monotone logic to solve the problem, then translate the results back to a non-monotonic logic. However, this seems cumbersome.

Could you please provide me with a book or paper reference on model theory in non-monotonic logics. Preferably, classical topics such as Compactness theorem, Incompleteness theorems and Stable theories should be included.

Comment: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-nonmonotonic/ has some references , but i doubt that there is something as detailed as you are looking for, the subject just doesn't allow it